# Cant insert emojis to the table by executing stored procedure

Tags: mysql

When I execute the query below, I am getting the value as given in the below table.

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';

"Variable_name"             "Value"
"character_set_client"      "utf8mb4"
"character_set_connection"  "utf8mb4"
"character_set_database"    "utf8mb4"
"character_set_filesystem"  "binary"
"character_set_results"     "utf8mb4"
"character_set_server"      "utf8mb4"
"character_set_system"       "utf8"
"collation_connection"       "utf8mb4_general_ci"
"collation_database"        "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
"collation_server"          "utf8mb4_general_ci"
```

When I am calling the `stored procedure`, I am getting the error as below

```
**Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8D\x89\xF0\x9F...' for column 'p_caption' at row 1**
```

When I execute the below query, the value gets inserted

```
INSERT INTO `orderdetails` (`OrderDetailsID`,`OrderId`,`Caption`)
VALUES('123456789','a1b16d012dcff03af923005ef9f98eb5','Happy birthday dear Ryan,,❤️')
```

But when I tried to call the below stored procedure,it doesnt work

```
CALL `sp_SaveOrderDetails`('123456789', 'a1b16d012dcff03af923005ef9f98eb5','Happy birthday dear Ryan,,❤️')
```

The `stored procedure` is as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_SaveOrderDetails`(IN p_orderDetailsID VARCHAR(40), IN p_orderId VARCHAR(40), IN p_caption TEXT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `orderdetails` (`OrderDetailsID`,`OrderId`,`Caption`)
    VALUES('123456789','a1b16d012dcff03af923005ef9f98eb5','Happy birthday dear Ryan,,❤️')
   END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The value get inserted into the table using the above query but it doesn't work when I call through `stored procedure`.I am using the field type as `TEXT`. I am new to mysql. Can anyone help

Comment: update your question with the error message and the inserted query that you have tried far

Comment: I have posted the error message@AnkitAgrawal

Comment: update your question with entire insert query

Comment: @Neemi facing the same problem

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Define utf8mb4 in IN p_caption
or change to longtext instead of TEXT:

example utf8mb4 in IN p_caption:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_SaveOrderDetails`(

IN p_orderDetailsID VARCHAR(40), 

IN p_orderId VARCHAR(40), 

IN p_caption TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4

)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO `orderdetails` (

`OrderDetailsID`,

`OrderId`,

`Caption`)

  VALUES(

'123456789',

'a1b16d012dcff03af923005ef9f98eb5',

'Happy birthday dear Ryan,,❤️')

   END$$
```

note: Your table orderdetails need to be CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 and COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci:

```
ALTER TABLE orderdetails CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```